# Aggregating labels of array for which corresponding input array contains all zero rows of input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am having a multi-dimensional `numpy` array of input such as this:

```
X = np.array([
            [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
              [1.0, 3.0, 1.0],
               [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]],
            
            [[[1.0,1.0,1.0],
               [1.0,1.0,1.0],
               [2.0,3.0,2.0],
               [1.0,1.0,1.0]]],
            
            [[[0.0,0.0,0.0],
              [1.0,2.0,1.0],
               [1.0,2.0,7.0],
               [1.0,1.0,1.0]]]
              ])
X.shape
(3, 1, 4, 3)
```

representing 3 instances of shape `(1,4,3)`.

This array has a corresponding array of `classes` for these instances.

```
y = np.array([0,1,2])
y
array([0,1,2])
```

The task is to count the number of instances by class, for which the last 2 rows of the array entries are all zeros.

So in the example above, it should be:

```
class       number
0             1
1             0
2             0
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure how an expression of the form:

```
for i, j in zip(X,y):
    #if rows of X[i] are zeros
        #update class j counter
```

Not sure if my logic above is correct

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
np.sum(np.all(X[:,:,-2:]==0, axis=(-1, -2)), axis=-1)
```

I'm sorry I deleted my last post because I misunderstood your question.

Comment: This `axis=(-1, -2)` means?

Comment: The last two axes.